# need to create new groovy project using gmaven plus archetype

Tags: maven, groovy

I need to create a new simple groovy projects using gmaven plus archetype. Can anyone share `archetypeArtifactId` for gmaven plus?

Here is a sample from gmaven:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.gmaven.archetypes \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=gmaven-archetype-basic
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any archetypes for GMavenPlus.

Comment: I'm the GMavenPlus creator/maintainer.  I felt like the [usage](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples) was simple enough archetypes they weren't needed (I don't really use archetypes myself).  I also felt that GMavenPlus (and even GMaven really) were being used in more ways these days than the classic joint Java/Groovy compilation projects (e.g. script execution, Groovy-only projects, etc).  But if you feel that these would be helpful, I can create archetypes for some of these cases.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10430775)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how my answer doesn't answer the question. What he wants to do is not possible because there aren't any GMavenPlus archetypes.

Comment: Your information provided is valuable, but it doesn't appear that there's an answer to this question. Your information is more of a comment on how there is no answer. I'm not sure why someone downvoted; I think my comment is more constructive. I do appreciate you taking the time to write this up, and I represent just one person's opinion.